# Why is OpenGL not drawing rectangle correctly

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to build game engine and I wanted to make it cross platform as possible, but BufferLayout abstraction might be suspect

I tried to debug it, but all numbers are correct. I also tried to wrap OpenGL calls around error checking code, but doesn't have any error.

```cpp
void OpenGLVertexArray::AddBuffers(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Buffer>>& buffers, const BufferLayout& layout)
{
    BZ_CORE_ASSERT(layout.GetElements().size() == buffers.size(), "Error, buffers and layout elements are not same size!");

    Enable();

    const auto& elements = layout.GetElements();
    uint32 offset = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffers.size(); ++i)
    {
        buffers[i]->Bind();
        const auto& element = elements[i];
        GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(i));
        GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(i, element.count, element.type, element.normalized ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE, layout.GetStride(), (const void*)offset));
        offset += BufferElement::GetSize(element.type) * element.count;
        buffers[i]->Unbind();
    }

    Disable();
}
```

If you need more code, then I published entire code to GitHub.
https://github.com/WhoseTheNerd/MinecraftPi

I expected rectangle to be rendered on screen, but it renders weird triangle. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu8ca.png

Comment: Have you read about [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output)?

Comment: Will read about this. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your offset processing seems to be a little strange to my eyes? Firstly you are casting a 32bit int into a pointer type. That's going to cause a bother if you are using a 64bit OS. If you change the offset to a uint8_t ptr, that will remove one of the problems (and remove the need for the cast).

```
const uint8_t* offset = 0;
```

One other issue i can see is that you're offset calculations seem somewhat confused. Are you sure you didn't just mean to pass in 0 for each offset?

```
    // bind an entirely new buffer
    buffers[i]->Bind();

    /* snip */

    // ok, so if buffers[0] contains the vertices. The offset for the next 
    // buffer will be (numVertices * sizeof(float) * 3) ?
    // So then I bind buffers[1] (let's say they contain vertex colours)
    // The array itself is (numVertices * sizeof(float) * 3) in size,
    // however the offset from the previous iteration is going to point
    // past the end of the buffer. That seems wrong to my eyes?
    offset += BufferElement::GetSize(element.type) * element.count;
```

It's almost as though the offset calculation code assumes that all of the data will come from a single buffer. However you seem to be binding a different buffer per element, which you would assume indicates an offset of zero for each buffer. Something tells me you shouldn't be calculating the offset at all, and should instead add it as a var to your element structure *(i.e. you will specify manually for each element - which will allow you to use both individual buffers, and multiple elements stored within a single buffer)*

One final issue, if element.type is anything other than GL_FLOAT or GL_HALF_FLOAT, you have a bug. For integer types you should be using glVertexAttribIPointer, and for GL_DOUBLE you need to use glVertexAttribLPointer.

Comment: The cast of a number to a pointer for the `gl…Pointer` function is an officially sanctioned hack, to avoid the introduction of new GL functions, yet to allow passing offsets instead of pointers. The `data` parameter of `gl…Pointer` functions that are used together with OpenGL Buffer Objects are not interpreted as pointers, but as plain numbers. Also the cast you're suggesting has no effect whatsoever, and in fact doesn't help in the slightest (what you wrote is simply wrong from perspective of programming in C).

Comment: It seems like a m_Stride is causing this. Will look further. And yes, offset really should be 0.